# I sent two values from client side var1 and var2, What I need is to display var 1 but when table is click, I want to get var 2

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, model-view-controller, razor

I have no idea on how to do this. If you have comments on the terms use, please let me know. I would love to know technical terms

```html
<tbody>
@foreach (var nbx in Model.Distinct())
{
    <tr>
        <td>@nbx.var1</td>
    </tr>
}
</tbody>
```

Script:

I want to get var2 here

```
$("#table td").click(function () {
     var id = $(this).text();
     alert(id);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The razor code will be run on the server, so the value of `var2` is lost by the time it gets to the client, and the jquery code won't be able to access it.

You'll have to store the value of `var2` somewhere on the page to reference it.  I would shove it in a `data-` attribute:

```
<tbody>
@foreach (var nbx in Model.Distinct())
{
    <tr>
        <td data-var2="@nbx.var2">@nbx.var1</td>
    </tr>
}
</tbody>
```

Then, you can grab it in your jquery function:

```
$("#table td").click(function () {
     var id = $(this).data('var2');
     alert(id);
});
```

Comment: Thank you @Jonesopolis but it comes back undefined :(

Comment: Thank you @Jonesopolis, your comment nudge me to the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

-This works

```
 $("#table td").click(function () {
                    var id = $(this).attr("data-var2");
               
    
                });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `onclick` Event,and pass var2 to the function in it:

```
<td onclick="GetData('@nbx.var2')">@nbx.var1</td>
```

js:

```
 function GetData(data) {
        alert(data);
    }
```